# How do i get my new value to go back through the if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to get the amount of days until the meeting to go back and print out the day the new meeting is on but I keep getting an integer instead of the string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NextMeeting {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int day, daysToMeeting = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the day of the week 0-6: ");
         day = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the days to meeting: ");
        daysToMeeting = scan.nextInt();

        if (day == 0) {
            System.out.println("Today is Sunday");
        } else if (day == 1) {
            System.out.println("Today is Monday");
        }
        else if (day == 2) {
            System.out.println("Today is Tuesday");
        }
        else if (day == 3) {
            System.out.println("Today is Wednesday");
        }
        else if (day == 4) {
            System.out.println("Today is Thursday");
        }
        else if (day == 5) {
            System.out.println("Today is Friday");
        }
        else if (day == 6) {
            System.out.println("Today is Saturday");
        }

        System.out.println("Today is: " + day);


        if( daysToMeeting >= 6) {
            day = daysToMeeting - 7;
        }
        else {
            day = day + 6;
        }
        System.out.println("Days to the meeting is " + daysToMeeting + " +days.");
        System.out.println("Meeting day is : " + Integer.toString(day));
    }
}
```

The output for days is still 3 but we need to get it to print out Wednesday. I don't know how to make that happen.

Comment: what do you mean by "I keep getting Integer instead of String"?

Comment: You will need to use a second variable or the equivalent of an Enum in Java.  The compiler does not know how to convert 3 to Wednesday. 1) inside your else ifs, assign a string to the value you want -or- 2) Create an Enum then you can index by an integer, sorry I do not develop in Java but the principles are the same for any language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
System.out.println("Meeting day is : " + DayOfWeek.of(day).toString());
```

You can also remove nested `if-else` statement and use `DayOfWeek` enum to display "Today is xyz-day".

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out integers because day is an int. It may be inefficient but an easy fix is to create a String variable and in another if-statement block below the daysToMeeting if-else block, assign the String to each corresponding integer, such as

```
String meetingDay;
if(day == 1){
    meetingDay = "Monday";
}
```

and then print out using the String variable.

```
System.out.println("Meeting day is : " + meetingDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method which will return the day of week String by passing the day int. Then print the result.

```
public String intToDayName(int day) {
            if(day > 6) {
                day = day % 7; 
            }
           if (day == 0) {

                return "Sunday"; 
            } else if (day == 1) {
                return "Monday";
            }
            else if (day == 2) {
                return "Tuesday"; 
            }
            else if (day == 3) {
                return "Wednesday";
            }
            else if (day == 4) {
                return "Thursday";
            }
            else if (day == 5) {
                return "Friday";
            }
            else if (day == 6) {
                return "Saturday";
            }
           return "Error";

    }
```

calling it in your prints:

```
System.out.println("Meeting day is : " + intToDayName(daysToMeeting));
System.out.println("Today is " + intToDayName(day));
```

If you actually want your code to go back and print the first if-else statements then I suggest looping.